# Adding a custom button after add to cart button in single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I am developing an ecommerce store based on WooCommerce.

I would like to add an View Cart Below the Add To Cart Button. It would be even better if it could only shown after adding at least 1 item in the cart successfully:

```
//add view cart button after add to cart button

add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button','view_cart_store');
function view_cart_store() { ?>
    <a class="button wc-forward" href="https://example.xxx/cart/"><?php _e( 'View Shopping Cart', 'woocommerce' ) ?></a>
    <?php
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use use [`WC_Cart is_empty()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_is_empty) method and [`wc_get_page_permalink()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_page_permalink.html) function:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button','view_cart_store');
function view_cart_store() {
    if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() )
        echo '<a class="button wc-forward" href="'.wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' ).'">'. __( 'View Shopping Cart', 'woocommerce' ) .'</a>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This code is tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted should already be displaying the cart link beneath the add to cart button.

In the example below, I'm checking the cart item count to determine whether to display a link.

Another minor update I've made is to use the WC function for retrieving the cart URL.

```
function wpse_view_cart_store() {
    if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ) : ?>

        <a class="button wc-forward" href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>"><?php _e( 'View Shopping Cart', 'woocommerce' ) ?></a>

    <?php endif;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'wpse_view_cart_store' );
```