# Additional custom button for specific single product page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, product

In WooCommerce on  need to create another button that redirects to "Contact Us" form below my current "Add to Cart" button for specific product page (example: http://offers.elements.com.sg/product/ha-power-dose-facial/).

End product page:

- There will be 2 different buttons for users to choose
- One will be "Add to Cart" that leads to PayPal page and the other will lead to "Contact Us" form
- Users can choose either one.

I'm using on OceanWP theme.

Answer (score 6):

Based on [additional add to cart button with fixed quantity in woocommerce single product pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759369/additional-add-to-cart-button-with-fixed-quantity-in-woocommerce-single-product/48759944#48759944) answer code, here is the way to do it:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'additional_single_product_button', 20 );
function additional_single_product_button() {
    global $product;

    // Define your targeted product IDs in the array below 
    $targeted_product_ids = array( 37, 53 );

    if( in_array( $product->get_id(), $targeted_product_ids ) ) {
        
        $link = home_url('/contact-us/'); // <== Here set button link
        $name = esc_html ( "Contact Us", "woocommerce" ); // <== Here set button name 
        $class = 'button alt';
        $style = 'display: inline-block; margin-top: 12px;';
    
        // Output
        echo '<br><a rel="no-follow" href="'.$link.'" class="'.$class.'" style="'.$style.'">'.$name.'</a>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

Other related answers:

- [Adding a custom button after add to cart button in single product pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43423819/adding-a-custom-button-after-add-to-cart-button-in-single-product-pages/43426508#43426508)
- [Add a button after add to cart and redirect it to some custom link in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38675675/add-a-button-after-add-to-cart-and-redirect-it-to-some-custom-link-in-woocommerc/38681079#38681079)
- [Custom Button next to “ADD TO CART” button of WooCommerce based on Product Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37228791/custom-button-next-to-add-to-cart-button-of-woocommerce-based-on-product-type/37229440#37229440)

Answer (score -1):

You can use some third party plugins that will provide features to add buttons on a single product page.

or you can add a button in a single product file using coding .. you can use a single product file in the child theme from the WooCommerce templates folder.

or you can also use hook to add button in shop loop like this :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'new_add_to_cart_button' );
function new_add_to_cart_button() {
    // Your button code.
}
```